# NDK Build command failed: while making any native project using ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I was tried changing android ndk version(r18b, r16b, r14b) but there is some error showing me. tried with 4 sample native code but attached error is getting in all sample codes.
So I think the error in gradle version or android studio version(may be deprecated issue).

> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing process
>   /home/bhavdip/Downloads/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r16b/ndk-build
>   with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk
>   APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-16
>   NDK_OUT=/home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib
>   APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> rm -f
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/*
>
> rm -f
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
>
> rm -f
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
>
> mkdir -p
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a
>
> echo [armeabi-v7a] "Gdbserver ": "[arm-linux-androideabi]
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver"
>
> install -p
>   /home/bhavdip/Downloads/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r16b/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
>
> echo [armeabi-v7a] "Gdbsetup ":
>   "/home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup"
>
> echo "set solib-search-path
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a"
>
> > /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
>
> echo "directory
>   /home/bhavdip/Downloads/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r16b/sysroot
>   /home/bhavdipb/AndroidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni
>   /home/bhavdipb/AndroidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/debug/jni
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni
>   /home/bhavdip/Downloads/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/system"
>
> > > /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
>
> make: *** No rule to make target
>   `/home/bhavdipb/AndroidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni/hello-jni.c',
>   needed by`
>   /home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/app//home/bhavdipb/AndroidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni/hello-jni.o'.
>   Stop.

I am using latest android studio 3.2.1

gradle version : 2.3.3 / 3.2.0 / 3.0.1

I want to run existing native code.

Do let me know if I miss any to give info related this issue.

Comment: Put the error message in your question instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make: *** No rule to make target `/home/bhavdipb/AndroidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni/hello-jni.c', needed by`/home/bhavdip/androidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/app//home/bhavdipb/AndroidStudioProjects/apps/testNDK/app/src/main/jni/hello-jni.o'. Stop.

Does your project include a jni/hello-jni.c? If so, do a clean build. Otherwise, that's your problem; your build script refers to a file that doesn't exist.